# video.js video size

Tags: size, video.js

I can't set the video size with video.js

i made a video node:

```
        videoNode = $('<video>');
        videoNode.attr('id', 'simulationVideo');
        $('#' + _config.videoTargetId).append(videoNode);
```

i set up the player:

```
    //create new player
    myPlayer = _V_("simulationVideo", {
        'id': _config.id,
        'preload': "auto",
        'controls': false,
        'autoplay': _config.autoplay

    }, function () {

        //set listeners for our controlbar
        //if (_config.controls) {
            controls = new Doczero.VideoPlayer.Controlbar();

            //$('#' + _config.controlbarTargetId).append(controls.html());

            //put listeners in place
            this.addEvent('timeupdate', controls.onTimeUpdate);
            this.addEvent('progress', controls.onBufferUpdate);
            this.addEvent('play', controls.onPlay);
            this.addEvent('pause', controls.onPause);

            //listen to controlls
            controls.CustomEvents.AddListener('onPressPlay', _self);

        //}
    });
```

i play a track:

```
    //set sources to play
    this.play = function (srcArray, newCallback) {
        //set source
        myPlayer.src(srcArray);
        myPlayer.play();

        //remove old callback
        if (callback != null) {
            myPlayer.removeEvent('ended', callback);
        }

        //add new ended callback
        myPlayer.removeEvent('ended', newCallback);
    }
```

everything seems to work nice, untill the video pops up 3 times bigger (it stays the orinigal size)

Comment: is the size of the <video> element being set?

Comment: Yes, i do set several height and witdh properties the way the video.js script is given on their site. BUT het <video> tag does not have the properties inside them, the wrapper which is created by video.js does...

Comment: just taking a look at their "custom code generator" here http://videojs.com/tag-builder/ shows the height and width on the video tag.  Not sure if this is the problem but you may try it

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The real problem is that videojs does copy the height of the video into the wrapper div, and removes is from the tag (i guess). When i put a height/width in the video tag in chrome, the video resizes like a charm!